# winXP dosen't respond to jquery .ajax() request

Tags: jquery

I use .ajax to get back html data that is passed throe json (php). works fine on win7 but not on winXP. i echoed out some text at the beginning of php file that send data back, but there is "blank page" coming back!

but everything works fine in win7 except winXP.

```
function feedPage(div_id, feed_id, to, page){
    $.ajax({
        url: iloc,
        type: "POST",
        data: {a: "feed_page", div_id: div_id, feed_id: feed_id, page: page, to: to},
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(d){
            var obj = eval('('+d+')');
            $("#page_now").html(obj.page);
            if(div_id == 1) {
                div_id = 0;
            }
            hideButton(obj.hide_button, div_id, feed_id, obj.page);
            delete obj["page"];
            delete obj["hide_button"];
            if(obj.rss_title) {
                $("#feed_title").html("<h1>"+obj.rss_title[0]+"</h1>");
                delete obj["rss_title"][0];
                $("#last_page").html(obj.last_page);
            }
            if(obj.all_feeds) {
                $(".jaunumi").append("ir");
                delete obj["all_feeds"];
            }
            $("#feed_id ul").scrollTop(0);
            $("#feed_id").empty();
            for (var i in obj){
                $("#feed_id").append(obj[i].title);
                $("#feed_id").append(obj[i].description);
            }
            if(div_id == 0) {
                var feed_div_offset = $("#feed_id").offset();
                var feed_div_offset_top = feed_div_offset.top - 100;
                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: feed_div_offset_top }, 'slow');
            }
            $(".tablo_slash").html("/");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It's probably the browser, not the OS. What browser are you using?

Comment: If the request returns JSON, why are you specifying `dataType: 'html'` then using `eval()` to turn it into a JSON object? Just use `dataType: 'json'` and jQuery will handle it for you.

Comment: What @AnthonyGrist said, + never use `eval()`. Use something like `$.parseJSON()` if you're parsing a JSON string to an object.

Comment: Firefox doesn't work with this and IE closes and reopens a new tab, but at the end IE shows content. + I tried dataType: "json"! still it doesn't return anything, this time i guess json it self has different name - after i changed datatype to"json". - sorry - i am noob at jquery...